# Ratchet vs PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, ratchet

What's the difference between PhoneGap and Ratchet. If I understand correctly, both are front end framworks for building mobile hybrid apps with HTML, CSS, and Javascript. Is one better than the other and if so why?

Comment: You didn't understand correctly, Ratchet is a front end framework, phonegap/cordova is a platform for building native mobile applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. So, you use Ratchet or any other front end framework to create the app, and use cordova to pack the app and use native features.

Answer (score 4):

**Phonegap** is the sugar coated version of the **cordova**. These are perform the main role of covert the HTML,JS,CSS to your desire platform file like **apk**,**ipa**(apple), etc.

**Ratchet** is complete the front end frameworks. So if your use this in your app, finally you need to phonegap or cordova for getting your application for desired your platform.

**Is one better than the other and if so why?**
**Ratchet** is front end framework. And **phonegap** is core part.  How did you compare Ratchet and phonegap?

**phonegap** or **cordova** are act the bridge between the mobile browser and native function of the desired platform. It is used to browser access the mobile hardware like camera,reading storage,read contacts,etc

Apache Cordova is an open-source mobile development framework. It allows you to use standard web technologies such as HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript for cross-platform development, avoiding each mobile platforms' native development language. Applications execute within wrappers targeted to each platform, and rely on standards-compliant API bindings to access each device's sensors, data, and network status.

**Use Apache Cordova if you are:**

1. a mobile developer and want to extend an application across more
   than one platform, without having to re-implement it with each
   platform's language and tool set.
2. a web developer and want to deploy a web app that's packaged for
       distribution in various app store portals.
3. a mobile developer interested in mixing native application
       components with a WebView (special browser window) that can access
       device-level APIs, or if you want to develop a plugin interface
       between native and WebView components.